# Why $\Delta y \neq \cos((2.03)^2+1)-2-(\cos(2^2+1)-2)$?

Tags: differential

On computing $\Delta y$ from $x=2$ to $x=2.03$:

If $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x) -f(x)$ and $y=\cos(x^2+1)-x$ why

$\Delta y \neq  \cos((2.03)^2+1)-2-(\cos(2^2+1)-2)$ ?

Asumming $\Delta x=0.03$ and $x=2$

Original solution is:

$\Delta y =  \cos((2.03)^2+1)-2.03-(\cos(2^2+1)-2)$

This implies:

$\Delta x =0.03$ and $x=2=2.03$?!

Context: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Differentials.aspx (Example 2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have misstated the $-x$ term for $x = 2.03$

Comment: @SimonS $x=2$ and $x+\Delta x=2.03$

Comment: Yes. See below.

Comment: $f(x)=\cos(x^2+1)-x \\ f(2.03)=\cos((2.03)^2+1)-2.03 \\ f(2)=\cos(2^2+1)-2$ And so $\Delta y =f(2.03)-f(2)=[\cos(2.03^2+1)-2.03]-[\cos(2^2+1)-2]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y = f(x) =  \cos(x^2 + 1) - x$ and thus

$$\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x) -f(x) = f(2.03) - f(2) = \left(\cos((2.03)^2+1)-\color{red}{2.03}\right)-(\cos(2^2+1)-2)$$

Comment: Then $x+\Delta x=2.06$

Comment: $x = 2$, $x + \Delta x = 2.03$